# Is there any way through which we can block all IP's except one IP with the help of IPSEC?

Tags: ipsec

Here i want to ask you that is there any way through which i can allow only my machine to access client servers as i want to secure my servers from hackers. for this i have find a lot but not able find a specific way to allow only my ip to access. If i blocks all IP then it blocks all the IP's but when create a rule to allow only my IP then the rule dosent works.

Can you suggest what may be the reason or can you suggest the solution.

Its for windows server 2003

Comment: Which Operating System?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking Windows, yes. You set up a default block rule that applies to all IPs. Then you set up another rule that permits TCP communication (or UDP, if that's necessary) to your set of IPs that you wish to permit. It could also be protocol based. For instance, a DMZ web server which needs to connect to a back-end SQL Server:

- Block all TCP/UDP from any source to the destination server.
- Permit all TCP/80 (HTTP) and TCP/443 (HTTPS) traffic from an external IP to the destination server.
- Permit mirrored TCP/1433 (assuming default TCP port for MSSQLServer) to internal IP address of the SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this question is about firewalling rather than IPSEC.  If you are only allowing IPSEC secured connections then you would simply only have an IPSEC SA (Security Association) for the chosen client.  This would not necessarily need to be tied to a specific IP and would be a good choice if you do not know the IP that you will be accessing the server from. Any client you do not have an SA for will not be able to get access.

If you know your IP address it is more likely what you want is to install either a software firewall on the client server or a hardware firewall in front of it that only allow access from your nominated IP.

You could also combine the approach so that your management traffic is encrypted in transit using IPSEC and the server is protected to only accept traffic from your host by a firewall.  IPSEC encryption may not be needed if the management already uses an encrypted channel (e.g. SSH or HTTPS).

Comment: In Windows, you can handle this with an IPSEC policy, too. In fact, it's best if you can do both, firewall and IPSEC policy. Defense in depth.